# Armature and mesh out of alignment

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, armature

So I made a hand in Blender, added an armature and an animation which worked perfectly. I went back to edit the mesh only slightly (just some smoothing), and afterwards the mesh is deformed when playing the animation. I am very new to Blender so I could have overlooked something obvious.

*Any help is appreciated.*

[image: Deformed Mesh]

Comment: Hello, maybe you've reworked while the armature was in Pose mode with the On Cage option enabled? So when back to rest pose it gets deformed...

Comment: @moonboots I've had a look and I'm not sure where to find the On Cage option to check, where would it be?

Comment: in the object Armature modifier, one of the top small buttons on the top

Comment: @moonboots Ah, I found it. And I think I've realized where I went wrong.  I applied the Armature modifier to the object previously, then realized that was a mistake and just added another one, which causes the issue you see in the image. I think applying the Armature made the first frame of the animation, the original pose for the object. So I think I need to adjust the animation to work with the second armature maybe. Since I applied the original so I cannot get it back to make any changes.

Comment: sure, if you've applied the modifier it has changed the shape of the mesh

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for your help :)